# How do you install multiple, separate instances of Ubuntu in WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

In Windows 10, how do you install multiple, separate instances of Ubuntu in WSL? I'd like separate instances for different work spaces. For instance one for Python development, one for Ruby development, one for .Net Core development, etc.  I know I could jam all of these into the same Ubuntu on WSL instance, but I'd rather have a separate one for each of these scenarios.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why not just install VirtualBox and be done?

Comment: @ivanivan This is just one more option besides full VM-s, Vagrant, Docker. Which one to choose depends on use case. Compared with VirtualBox this provides access to Windows, and starts almost instantly.

Comment: We use surface pro machines which you cannot run virtualbox on.  We also tried Hyper-V and had issues with that too because of our infrastructure. Like Braca said it depends upon what you are using it for and also any restrictions you may have due to your infrastructure.

Comment: > Why not just install VirtualBox and be done? - I think, VM is more resource-intensive and unwieldy solution.

Comment: Related: [Upgrade Ubuntu in WSL2 from 20.04 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428423/upgrade-ubuntu-in-wsl2-from-20-04-to-22-04).

Answer (score 163):

The newer [`wsl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference) command's import/export feature can readily create copies of a distro without installing any additional tools or using RegEdit.  For example

```
cd C:\Users\MattSlay
wsl --export Ubuntu ubuntu.tar
wsl --import UbuntuRuby .\UbuntuRuby ubuntu.tar
wsl --import UbuntuPython .\UbuntuPython ubuntu.tar
wsl --import UbuntuDotNet .\UbuntuDotNet ubuntu.tar
wsl -d UbuntuRuby
```

`wsl -d <distro>` launches the distro. If [WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install) has been installed, then the distro can be converted between versions during `--import` using the `--version` option:

```
wsl --import UbuntuRuby .\UbuntuRuby ubuntu.tar --version 2
```

A smaller distro, such as [Alpine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/alpine-wsl/9p804crf0395), can make experimentation much faster. Finally, `wsl --import` can read from standard input `-` and `wsl --export` can write to standard output `-`.  This allows a compression program to be used to save disk space if desired.

Side note:
The default login of imported distro is root. 
For Build 18980 and later, you may create or modify `/etc/wsl.conf` to set your default login user instead of fiddling with registry or login with `wsl -u <username>`. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#user-settings)

Content of /etc/wsl.conf. It might take effect after shutdown or logout.

```
[user]
default=<your-default-username>
```

Comment: Note issue: Couldn't import wsl2 distribution [#4530](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4530)

Comment: The new instance will have the same user with old instance (a copy, of course), but will use `root` as default login, and I can't use `ubuntu config --default-user <username>` because `ubuntu` is actually an .exe and the approach above creates a directory. How do I change to my user instead of root?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4276#issuecomment-509364493 notes how to change the default user: set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\{MY-UUID}\DefaultUid (DWORD) to the id from /etc/passwd

Comment: Might work for command line launching of WSL, doesn't create the APPX link so there's no launcher item. Really want launcher item.

Comment: Also for myself if I find this here again: `wsl --unregister <distroName>` for removing n image/distro

Comment: Thank you for this post. I made a GUI based on that: https://github.com/bostrot/wsl2-distro-manager

Comment: @robrich. It's much more easier to add an `/etc/wsl.conf` to setup default login user. Refer to the [later comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4276#issuecomment-553367389) in the link you provided. Or the [doc from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#user)

Answer (score 27):

It is possible, but requires some work. You can use [LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline) - "A full-featured utility for Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)".

You can install it via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install): `choco install lxrunoffline`, or download and unzip.

You might want to add *LxRunOffline.exe* to your PATH.

`https://lxrunoffline.apphb.com/download/{distro}/{version}` will redirect to download page for desired distro. In this case it would be .../ubuntu/xenial or similar, according to [lxrunoffline wiki](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline/wiki#quick-start), or you can download directly from [Canonical](https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/).

Then you can:
`LxRunOffline install -n someName -d where/to/install -f path/to/downloaded/distro` multiple times with different names and target directories.

Then you can `lxrunoffline -w -n someName` to start desired installation, and finally, you can create multiple shortcuts on the desktop with different options for specific work spaces.
LxRunOffline available commands:

```
list           List all installed distributions.
get-default    Get the default distribution, which is used by bash.exe.
set-default    Set the default distribution, which is used by bash.exe.
install        Install a new distribution.
uninstall      Uninstall a distribution.
register       Register an existing installation directory.
unregister     Unregister a distribution but not delete the installation directory.
move           Move a distribution to a new directory.
duplicate      Duplicate an existing distribution in a new directory.
run            Run a command in a distribution.
get-dir        Get the installation directory of a distribution.
get-env        Get the default environment variables of a distribution.
set-env        Set the default environment variables of a distribution.
get-uid        Get the UID of the default user of a distribution.
set-uid        Set the UID of the default user of a distribution.
get-kernelcmd  Get the default kernel command line of a distribution.
set-kernelcmd  Set the default kernel command line of a distribution.
get-flags      Get some flags of a distribution. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt826872(v=vs.85).aspx for details.
set-flags      Set some flags of a distribution. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt826872(v=vs.85).aspx for details.
version        Get version information about this LxRunOffline.exe.
```

Comment: Just tried LxRunOffline and it's seriously awesome. Thank you and thanks to the LxRunOffline team.

Answer (score 18):

First we have to find the install location of that Windows Store Appx. Here is a Powershell script to find that path. Enter the distribution name at first (e.g. `Ubuntu18.04`).

```ps
$DistroName=Read-Host "Enter Distribution Name"
$path = (Get-AppxPackage "*$DistroName*").InstallLocation
echo $path
Invoke-Item $path
pause
```

The installation path for Ubuntu 18.04 will be:

```
%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804.2018.427.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc
```

In the PS script, `Invoke-Item` will open that path in File Explorer. If that path is not visible or shows any security issue, then grant permission to access that folder from its Properties menu. Now copy just these two required files:

1. Distribution userspace tarball named as **install.tar.gz** (or any TAR.GZ file).
2. Main executable file to install, named as Ubuntu.exe or Ubuntu1804.exe or Ubuntu1604.exe etc.

Here comes the next section. **Backup** and then delete the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss`. Place those two files in a folder structure like this (or as you want):

```
C:\MyFiles
|
+-- UbuntuPython
|   |
|   +-- ubuntu.exe
|   +-- install.tar.gz
|
+-- UbuntuRuby
    |
    +-- ubuntu.exe
    +-- install.tar.gz
```

The folder **names should be different**. Now double click on the first copied `.exe` excutable, wait until it installs. Open `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\<some-GUID>` and change the `DistributionName` string registry to `UbuntuPython` (or any). Repeat the procedure with every instances. The GUID will be new one for every instances. Make sure you **change the `DistributionName` registry** entry to different values for each one, otherwise `ubuntu.exe` will execute `wsl.exe` instead of installing. See the source code of those EXE files here [GitHub: Microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL-DistroLauncher).

Comment: Changing the `DistributionName` registry does not seem to work anymore. Instead, it will get corrupted. Any updates on this?

Comment: "Works on my machine"

Answer (score 14):

Rather than duplicating distributions from Microsoft Store or *.appx* files, another solution is by utilizing Docker in existing Linux distribution running on WSL. This method is actually explained in [WSL Docs by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/use-custom-distro).

This method is beneficial because you can utilize a variety of distros that have been available in the Docker registry.

For example, you already have **Ubuntu-18.04** distribution installed from Microsoft Store.

1. Run the distribution from terminal

```sh
wsl -d Ubuntu-18.04
```

2. Install Docker for Ubuntu by following [instruction from Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)
3. Run docker service

```
service docker start
```

4. Run a container with any Linux distribution you desired, for example, Ubuntu 20.04

```
docker run -d ubuntu:20.04
```

5. List all containers, and keep the Container ID of the distribution you desired

```
docker ps -a
```

6. Export the selected container into a *.tar* file, for example, the Container ID is *123123abcabc* and you want to store the exported file in `C:\data`.
   WSL mounts your Windows directory into `/mnt` directory on the running Linux. If you have a `C:\data` directory on Windows, its content can be accessed on your Linux in `/mnt/c/data` directory.

```
docker export 123123abcabc > /mnt/c/data/exported-ubuntu-20.04.tar
```

Now, the exported file is available in `C:\data\exported-ubuntu-20.04.tar`.

7. Exit from Linux, back to Windows terminal, then import the exported container as a new distribution with any desired name and stored in any location in Windows

```
exit
wsl --import anyName C:\data\anyLocation C:\data\exported-ubuntu-20.04.tar
```

8. Now, you can see your new distribution in the list and run it

```
wsl --list -v
wsl -d anyName
```

Comment: Great way of using this feature!

Answer (score 9):

I recently had the same issue, as I am working with different companies at the same time, and needed a script that could easily create a new WSL2 instance, and just as easily delete it.

Deletion by itself is not hard, as the official command `wsl --unregister <distro_name>` works just fine, and gets rid of the WSL2 instances perfectly, without leaving any trace.

Creation however, can be troublesome or even tedious. My script does just this: https://github.com/IAL32/WSL2-Create-Distro

The following example creates a WSL2 instance using Ubuntu20.04 (Focal Fossa) using a previously downloaded
tarball (the example uses the following one: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/focal/current/focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz), creates a user with username `myuser`
and adds it to the group `sudo`. It also sets the user password to the one given in the pipeline, and the password for the root user, also given in the pipeline.

```
.\CreateLinuxDistro.ps1 -INPUT_FILENAME .\focal-server-cloudimg-amd64-wsl.rootfs.tar.gz -OUTPUT_DIRNAME "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages\ubuntu2004-test-1" -OUTPUT_DISTRONAME ubuntu2004-test-1 -CREATE_USER 1 -CREATE_USER_USERNAME myuser -ADD_USER_TO_GROUP 1 -ADD_USER_TO_GROUP_NAME sudo -SET_USER_AS_DEFAULT myuser
```

Under the hood, if a new user is created it will also change its default shell from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`.